# How to embed mp3 and wma file in html

Tags: html, audio-streaming

I want to embed mp3 and wma files in my website. I embed plugins for video file like wmv and its working. That plugin code is available at

```
http://www.walkernews.net/2008/08/17/windows-media-player-how-to-embed-wmv-file-in-html-code/
```

Now i want to play mp3 and wma files

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this javascript plug in which works fine : http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/